# Are there some special rules to set a variable into a multidimensional array for php?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, variable-assignment

Ok, I'm stumped here.  I'm trying to set a variable into a multidimensional associative array, and I do not understand why this is not working.

```
class myClass
{
    private $someProblem = 'data_is_here';

    private $access_array = 
        array
        ('key1a' => array 
            (
                'key2a' => array('key3a' => 'data1','key3b' => 'data4', 'key3c' => $someProblem),
                'key2b' => array('key3a' => 'data2','key3b' => 'data5', 'key3c' => $someProblem),
                'key2c' => array('key3a' => 'data3','key3b' => 'data6', 'key3c' => $someProblem)
            )
        ...more array values here, same pattern...
}
```

In this iteration, I get:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$someProblem' (T_VARIABLE) in myclass.class.php on line 10
```

I've tried changing $someProblem to a constant, making it static, making it public, etc but I am always getting an error where the variable appears (error changes, but always fatal).

Appreciate the help in advance- especially, please explain why it's not failing at 'key3a'=>'data1', and why if I replace $someProblem with 'data_is_here', it works.

Comment: The syntax highlighter shows your mistake. Any basic text editor would do the same.

Comment: probably the double single quotes '' after key3b, notice the color of the text is offset afterwards

Comment: `'key3b''` extra single quote

Comment: ugh... thank you.  sorry.

Comment: Please also note that you can't define a class property to be a variable value.  All class property assignments need to be statically deterministic. Once you fix the syntax error noted above, this will be your next problem. Read first paragraph here http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Comment: Actually- that's not it.  Those were introduced when I removed the actual data for posting here.  editing now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from the quote problem, you cannot do what you want to do in php. According to the manual on [class properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this
>   initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to
>   be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time
>   information in order to be evaluated.

So you cannot use a variable to assign a value to a class property where you declare it. You would need to do that in the constructor.

And then you could not use `$someProblem`, you would need to use `$this->someProblem`.

Comment: I took the manual to mean that I could not use a variable- was still getting an error using a constant.  By the comments, I assume constants also cannot be used in this context?  (I'm working on the constructor now- just want to understand better)-  thanks for the help!

Comment: @SteveR Yes, a constant cannot be evaluated at compile time either as it could come from a completely different script or include.